# matplotlib: yticklabels on the secondary y-axis doesn't work with manual tick-labelling in log-scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to make a plot that has both x and y axis in log-scale, and has a secondary y-axis also in log-scale but with different values. I am using `plt.twinx()` to do so. I am defining the `ticklabels` by hand because I want them to appear in specific locations and formatted as, for example, 10 instead of 10^1. This works in the primary axis (left), but it ignores my
`ax2.set_yticklabels` when I put the plot in log-scale. Does anyone know why does this happen and how to overcome it?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

fig,ax= plt.subplots(1,1,figsize = (6,4),dpi=100)
x=np.random.uniform(0,4500,200)
y=np.random.uniform(0,400,200)
y2=np.random.uniform(0,200,200)

ax.plot(x,y,'k.',alpha=0.6)
ax.plot(x,y2,'r.',alpha=0.6)
ax.tick_params(axis="y", direction="inout", length=10, width=1.1)
ax.tick_params(axis="x", direction="inout", length=10, width=1.1, top=True)
ax.tick_params(axis="y",which='minor',direction="inout", length=6,width=0.9)
ax.tick_params(axis="x",which='minor',direction="inout", length=6,width=0.9, top=True)
ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.set_yticks([1,10,100])
ax.set_yticklabels([1,10,100],fontsize=fs)    
ax.set_xticks([1,10,100,1000])
ax.set_xticklabels([1,10,100,1000],fontsize=fs)
ax.set_ylabel('$\Omega(\Omega\odot)$',fontsize=fs)
ax.set_ylim(0.1,400)
ax.set_xlim(0.3,7000)
#secondary axis
ax2 = ax.twinx() 
ax.plot(x+1e6,y,'k.')
ax2.get_yticks()
ax2.set_yticks([0.1,1,10,100,1000])
ax2.set_yticklabels([10,1,0.1,0.01,0.001])
ax2.set_ylim(0.1,400)  
ax2.set_yscale("log")
```

[image]

Note that if I comment out the `ax2.set_yscale("log") and` ax.set_yscale("log")`,` set_yticklabels` works just fine.
[image]

Comment: As the logscale changes the ticks, you need to set the logscale before other changes. So, before `ax2.get_ticks()`. If that isn't sufficient, you might try to change the logformatter to a scalarformatter. Something like `from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter;
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())`.  Also `from matplotlib.ticker import NullLocator: ax2.set_minor_locator(NullLocator())` might be needed to suppress the minor ticks which don't coincide with the renamed tick labels.

Comment: This is so simple?! Changing the position of `ax2.set_yscale("log")` to before `ax2.get_ticks()` worked just fine! Thanks a lot!